# error in compiling project depends on boost

Tags: macos, unix, boost, cmake

I have 2 static libraries libA , libB written in c++

libA depends on some boost components, i used cmake file and hunter to create this lib project

in libA cmake file i used

```
add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )
hunter_add_package(Boost COMPONENTS random system thread filesystem chrono atomic)
find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED random system thread filesystem chrono atomic)
```

libA built correctly on window,osx and unix.
libB linked to libA, libB built properly on windows but it didn't compile correctly on unix and osx.

the error on linux was fatal error boost/algorithm/string.hpp no such file or directory
and on osx it was the same error with different file
i checked the file, it was there

[image]

what i missed ? why it worked on window and not on osx ?

Comment: Is given include file (`boost/algorithm/string.hpp`) exists and which its precise location? You need to link `libB` to Boost, as it also uses its functionality, and `include_directories()`. In any case neither `libA` dependency nor given part of CMake script you provide are unrelated to the problem. You need to post (in the question itself) CMake code which related to building `libB` library.

Comment: there was specific path for this file, it was exists. in "libB" i don't use any function from boost do i need to add link to boost . i don't understand why it built on windows ?  i will post my cmake code soon.i don't have access to my pc now :)

Comment: The error is *compile* error, and it corresponds to some line of code. As it is error in `libB` compilation, then `libB` sources include this file, directly or indirectly. According to the output (make it textual, please), `libB` uses `http_client.h`, which indirectly uses Boost.

Comment: i added boost include directories to "libB" and it worked Thank you @Tsyvarev